# Controller function not working after overwrite afterExecute : M2

Tags: magento2, admin-controller

> Di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save">
        <plugin name="mymodule" type="Module\Name\Plugin\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save"/>
</type>
```

> Save.php

```
<?php 
namespace Module\Name\Plugin\Controller\Adminhtml\Category;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;

class Save {

    protected $resultRedirect;

    protected $resultRawFactory;

    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    protected $layoutFactory;

    protected $stringToBoolInputs = [
        'custom_use_parent_settings',
        'custom_apply_to_products',
        'is_active',
        'include_in_menu',
        'is_anchor',
        'use_default' => ['url_key'],
        'use_config' => ['available_sort_by', 'filter_price_range', 'default_sort_by']
    ];

    private $storeManager;


    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $result,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
        $this->resultRedirect = $result;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function afterExecute()
    {


        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/category_save.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);

$logger->info("Info");


        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */


        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        /*$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);*/

        $category = $this->_initCategory();

        if (!$category) {
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('catalog/*/', ['_current' => true, 'id' => null]);
        }

        $data['general'] = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $categoryPostData = $data['general'];

        $isNewCategory = !isset($categoryPostData['entity_id']);
        $categoryPostData = $this->stringToBoolConverting($categoryPostData);
        $categoryPostData = $this->imagePreprocessing($categoryPostData);
        $categoryPostData = $this->dateTimePreprocessing($category, $categoryPostData);
        $storeId = isset($categoryPostData['store_id']) ? $categoryPostData['store_id'] : null;
        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId);
        $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($store->getCode());
        $parentId = isset($categoryPostData['parent']) ? $categoryPostData['parent'] : null;
        if ($categoryPostData) {
            $category->addData($this->_filterCategoryPostData($categoryPostData));
            if ($isNewCategory) {
                $parentCategory = $this->getParentCategory($parentId, $storeId);
                $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
                $category->setParentId($parentCategory->getId());
            }

            /**
             * Process "Use Config Settings" checkboxes
             */

            $useConfig = [];
            if (isset($categoryPostData['use_config']) && !empty($categoryPostData['use_config'])) {
                foreach ($categoryPostData['use_config'] as $attributeCode => $attributeValue) {
                    if ($attributeValue) {
                        $useConfig[] = $attributeCode;
                        $category->setData($attributeCode, null);
                    }
                }
            }

            $category->setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId());

            if (isset($categoryPostData['category_products'])
                && is_string($categoryPostData['category_products'])
                && !$category->getProductsReadonly()
            ) {
                $products = json_decode($categoryPostData['category_products'], true);
                $category->setPostedProducts($products);
            }
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'catalog_category_prepare_save',
                ['category' => $category, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
            );

            /**
             * Check "Use Default Value" checkboxes values
             */
            if (isset($categoryPostData['use_default']) && !empty($categoryPostData['use_default'])) {
                foreach ($categoryPostData['use_default'] as $attributeCode => $attributeValue) {
                    if ($attributeValue) {
                        $category->setData($attributeCode, null);
                    }
                }
            }

            /**
             * Proceed with $_POST['use_config']
             * set into category model for processing through validation
             */
            $category->setData('use_post_data_config', $useConfig);

            try {
                $categoryResource = $category->getResource();
                if ($category->hasCustomDesignTo()) {
                    $categoryResource->getAttribute('custom_design_from')->setMaxValue($category->getCustomDesignTo());
                }

                $validate = $category->validate();
                if ($validate !== true) {
                    foreach ($validate as $code => $error) {
                        if ($error === true) {
                            $attribute = $categoryResource->getAttribute($code)->getFrontend()->getLabel();
                            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                                __('Attribute "%1" is required.', $attribute)
                            );
                        } else {
                            throw new \Exception($error);
                        }
                    }
                }

                $category->unsetData('use_post_data_config');

                $category->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the category.'));
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
                $this->_getSession()->setCategoryData($categoryPostData);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
                $this->_getSession()->setCategoryData($categoryPostData);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('Something went wrong while saving the category.'.$e->getMessage()));
                $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
                $this->_getSession()->setCategoryData($categoryPostData);
            }
        }
}
}
```

**Getting this errors**

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: Module\Name\Plugin\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save::$resultRedirectFactory in 



also getting an error near this line

$category = $thianyonetCategory();
```

If any one idea please share and help me as soon as

Comment: your approach is technically wrong what you want will not be done in after plugin. you have to change it to around plugin or use preference to rewrite this class.second option is better in your case.

Answer (score -1):

You have to changes

> $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

to

> $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create();

see your _construct  function, You are to injected as

```
\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $result
```

and    `$this->resultRedirect = $result;`

has result factory.

Also, Also, you have to remove `parent::__construct($context);`

Comment: getting this error for this : parent::__construct($context); 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to use a class property ($resultRedirectFactory) which doesn't exist in your class (not declared).

To make this working, you have to change in your class:

1) from `protected $resultRedirect;` to `protected $resultRedirectFactory;`

2) from

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $result,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->resultRedirect = $result;
    ...
}
...
```

to

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: getting this error for this : parent::__construct($context); 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in

Comment: @Bhavsar Hey, your class should extend abstract admin panel action in order to work

Comment: ` Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action`